# A way to output pyunit test name in setup()

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is there a way in python for a pyunit test to output the test it's currently running.  Example:

```
def setUp(self):
    log.debug("Test %s Started" % (testname))

def test_example(self):
    #do stuff

def test_example2(self):
    #do other stuff

def tearDown(self):
    log.debug("Test %s Finished" % (testname))
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use `self._testMethodName`. This is [inherited from the `unittest.TestCase`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/unittest/case.py#L403) parent class.

```
def setUp():
    print("In method", self._testMethodName)
```

Comment: Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: There's not any. As you might guess from the underscore prefix on the attribute name, this is an internal attribute that's not intended to be exposed.  I do wish that there was a proper way to do this, though.

Answer (score 19):

```
self.id().split('.')[-1]
```

You can find the Documentation at:
http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id

edit:
For 2.7 users,
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id

Answer (score 6):

You can use`str(self.id()).split()[4]`. It could be found here http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id