# How to have different test documentation for subclasses in pyunit?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234551/how-can-i-override-the-test-name-in-pyunit) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504622/a-way-to-output-pyunit-test-name-in-setup) but still am curious about how pyunit is meant to work for my use case.

I want to test the same method for multiple inputs. To do this, I created a class with several test methods, and two subclasses from it that have different `setUp` methods.

Something like this:

```
class Test_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    # abstract class, do not actually add this to the test suite!
    def test_01_preserves(self):
        """Foo preserves bazness correctly"""
        self.assertTrue(is_preserved(self.foo.baz))
        ....
    ...

class Test_Foo_simple(Test_Foo):
    """test Foo for some simple input"""
    def setUp(self):
        self.input = ""
        self.params = {}
        self.foo = Foo(self.input, self.params)

class Test_Foo_complex(Test_Foo):
    """test Foo for some complex input"""
    def setUp(self):
        self.input = "complicated stuff"
        self.params = {"bar" : 3}
        self.foo = Foo(self.input, self.params)

...
```

followed by adding the second two classes to a `TestSuite` and running that with `TextTestRunner`.

Now the output will be:

```
Foo preserves bazness correctly ... ok
...
Foo preserves bazness correctly ... ok
...
```

with no obvious way to keep track of which test case is being run at which point.

How do I fix this?

What I'm doing at the moment is adding an `__init__` method to each subclass that looks like:

```
super(Test_Foo_simple, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
self._testMethodDoc = self._testMethodDoc + "(simple)"
```

which seems like an awful hack, and not guaranteed to work on future versions of pyunit.  I could define another local variable with the desired docstring and subclass `TextTestRunner` to use that instead, but that brings its own problems. Is there a better way around this?