# Getting nose's numeric test ID in a test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

I have tests that I run with nose, and I'd like to make them run in parallel using the `--processes` flag. Every test opens a port which is configurable, and I'd like to calculate the port number based on the test number that appears in the printout when using the `--with-id` flag, as shown in the following example from [here](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/testid.html):

```
% nosetests -v --with-id
#1 tests.test_a ... ok
#2 tests.test_b ... ok
#3 tests.test_c ... ok
```

When looking for a solution I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16710858), which uses `self._testMethodName` and `self.id()`, but those don't work for me because they're string IDs based on the test's name and path.

Is there a way where I can get the printed numeric ID that appears when using `--with-id`?