# Difference using class and unittest class with nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm writing some tests and test them with `nosetests`

All my tests are in multiples classes from `object`, and I try to access to the test name (like `test_ipam_get.TestIPAMGet.test_noAuth`).

Example test class :

```py
class TestIPAMGet(object):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        cls.web = app.test_client()

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        pass

    def test_noAuth(self):
        client = self.web.get('/api/v0.1/')
        assert_equal(client.status_code , 401)
```

Nose produce me this output :
`test_ipam_get.TestIPAMGet.test_noAuth... ok`

I tried to access to the test name. According to [A way to output pyunit test name in setup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504622/a-way-to-output-pyunit-test-name-in-setup), I can inherit from `unittest.Testcase` and use `self.id()` and it works.
But now, my nose output change to :
`test_noAuth (test_ipam_get.TestIPAMGet) ... ok`

1. **Can you explain why and what's the difference ?**
2. **Is it possible to get the test name without using the inheritance ?**